How reducing the expression, making it still equal to the original can give different solution?
Consider $\dfrac{x^2+x-2}{\sqrt{x+6}-2}$. For $x=-2$ it is $\dfrac{0}{0}$.
However, if we just express $x^2+x-2$ as $(x+2)(x-1)$, divide both numerator and denominator by $(\sqrt{x+6}+2)$ we will get
$$\dfrac{(x+2)(x-1)(\sqrt{x+6}+2)}{x+2}$$
That allows us to reduce the $x+2$ and get of the indeterminate, giving the answer $-12$.
So, once again - $\dfrac{x^2+x-2}{\sqrt{x+6}-2} - \dfrac{(x+2)(x-1)(\sqrt{x+6}+2)}{x+2} = 0$, i.e. $\dfrac{x^2+x-2}{\sqrt{x+6}-2} = \dfrac{(x+2)(x-1)(\sqrt{x+6}+2)}{x+2}$, while they have different value at $x=-2$.
It seems like there is a difference what to do first (if it is why? proof?) - reduce first $x+2$ in numerator with $x+2$ in denominator, i.e. reduce zero in numerator with zero in denominator, or first multiply zero in numerator by all left stuff, giving the zero, and divide it by zero, or first divide $(x-1)(\sqrt{x+6}+2)$ by zero, and then multiply by zero.
Is not it a contradiction? Where is the trick?

If, in your first expression, you set $x=-2$ then the numerator is $(-2)^2+x-2=4-2-2=0$.  Not $4$, as you claim.

@lulu, You are right, fixed that

But, then, I don't understand your question. The Limit as $x\to -2$ is defined by looking at the function near, but not actually at, $x=-2$.  Therefore, if you have found a more sensible function which coincides with yours near, but not at, $x=-2$, you can use that function to evaluate the limit.

The transformations you perform are only valid for $x\neq -2$, and for those values you get a correct equivalent expression. When $x=-2$ your expression is still not defined. However, to compute a limit, that's precisely what you need: you need to know the values around the limit point, and your computation provides that, and lets you conclude what those values converge to. The only tiny shortcut happens at the end, where technically you should take a limit of your new expression as $x\to -2$ but since now you are working with a continuous function, you know you can just as well plug in $-2$.

@lulu, consider it not as limit. I removed limit part at all. It is just two expressions that are equal, but have different values. How?

@MichalAdamaszek, do not consider a limit, please.  I removed limit part at all. It is just two expressions that are equal, but have different values. How?

Without the limit the initial expression is simply not well-defined at $x=-2$.

They are equal for all $x\neq -2$.  At that point, one side is defined while the other isn't.

But why not take a simpler example?  $\frac xx$ coincides with $1$ for all $x\neq 0$.  Same idea.

@lulu is $\dfrac{abc}{a}$ equal to $b*c$?

For all triples with $a\neq 0$, yes.  It is undefined if $a=0$.

@lulu You stated that "it is undefined", but I asked about equality. If $a=0$, are they equal?

I feel like I am just repeating myself.  $(a,b,c)\mapsto \frac {abc}a$ is undefined if $a=0$.  But $bc$ is perfectly well defined if $a=0$.  Therefore, they are not equal at $a=0$.

@lulu, okay, so according to You, if there are undefined and defined function at some value, they are not equal, generally, right? If they are not equal at some of values, they are not equivalent expressions in generall, right?

@lulu, okay but You are rather stating about maps, about functions, when stating they are not defined somewhere. You probably referring to the domain. But can it be applied to an expression? Expression, is not an equality. As I understand, we can compare expressions, but can we consider their domains? Do they have domains?

@VV_721 moved to right from equal sign

The "domain of an expression", without any more information, exists only as a convention in the context you are working with. Assuming that we work with real numbers and real functions it is natural to assume the domain of your expression is $[-6,\infty)\setminus{-2}$, and everybody would reasonably make that assumption from the context of your question, but it is not dictated by any definition.

@MichalAdamaszek, so, if apply so called "identity transformations" to the equation or the expression I can actually change it, so it will not be to the original?

You could potentially shrink its domain. For example if you perform your procedure backwards then from an expression valid for all $x\geq -6$ you get an expression valid for $x\geq -6$ and $x\neq -2$ (and they are equal whenever both are well-defined). You have to shrink the domain even before applying the transformation, just to be able to justify that the application makes sense.

there's a mistake, not a contradiction.
Actually, you cannot cancel the factor (x + 2) in your equation unless you assume that x + 2 ≠ 0, i.e. x ≠ 2
This is because division by zero is undefined in mathematics, so if you are dividing any number or function by another, you have to assume that its value is not zero.
And if you assumed it, you can't put back that value in the equation.
`
